# Change MySQL root password in MAMP on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, mamp

I have MAMP installed on my Mac OS X, which is installed within my Applications folder.

The problem I am having is that I would like to change my "root" password which I have currently set to a new password, within one of my database schemas.

I have tried to locate mysqladmin but to no avail.

What is the query for changing this existing password?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it - used:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2):

MAMP installation on Mac OS X
All Mysql command files are located in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin

MAMP default credentials are:
 user: root
 password: root

Answer (score 1):

I found that running the SQL statement above locked me out of PHPMyAdmin, logically.   If you also want access to the graphical interface, go to /bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php and updated your password there.   You may want to update the shell scripts in /bin too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try runningthe following in the terminal:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password newpassword
```